# EditText Int number Validation for ID number 0-1000

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext, int

I am doing homework and I have gotten pretty far alone. My next step in the app is * Customer ID should be between 0-1000. If user enters any value above 1000, then you need to display an error message.

I don't know how to do this. I am watching videos and going to other sites to see if anything is similar but nothing is clicking. here is my code so far.

```
String name, address;
    int custID= 0;

    EditText nameInput;
    EditText addressInput;
    EditText custIDInput;

    Button submitButton;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    nameInput = this.<EditText>findViewById(R.id.NameeditText);
    addressInput = this.<EditText>findViewById(R.id.addresseditText);
    custIDInput = this.<EditText>findViewById(R.id.CustIDeditText);
    submitButton = this.findViewById(R.id.SubmitButton);


    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {


            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Customer.class);

            name = nameInput.getText().toString();
            address = addressInput.getText().toString();
            custID = Integer.valueOf(custIDInput.getText().toString());
            if(! custID > 0 && < 1000)
                custIDInput.setError("Error Customer ID: enter number 1-1000");

            i.putExtra("Value1", name);
            i.putExtra("Value2", custID);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
```

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong? Is there something I need to import? 
Thanks!

Comment: From what I'm seeing from the condition that sets the error, it seems that the condition you've entered is invalid. (It should just be one condition where the customer ID is over 1000. You don't have to invert the result of the condition - and that's not the right way to invert multiple conditions.) (P.S. Does the condition also state that an error should be shown if the ID entered is less than 0?)

Comment: I guess not... let me see what happens when I erase the extra condition.

Comment: Secondly, please consider formatting your code such that it is easier to read.

Comment: So that fixed the error I was getting but the error message and the constraints still are not working.

Comment: And by the way, if you don't understand what I mean, it's essentially you check whether `custID` is more than `1000` and set the error if that is true. (Optionally, you can also add an `else` block to the conditional statement which sets the error to null such that an error won't be shown if the user's input is within the constraints 0 - 1000.)

Comment: If any of the answers helped, please consider marking one of the answers as accepted and/or upvote them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your conditional statement isn't right in the first place.

The condition you've specified states that:

> Customer ID should be between 0-1000. If user enters any value *above 1000*, then you need to display an error message. (Emphasis is mine)

Essentially, this means that the error message should only be shown if the user enters a value above 1000. This would translate to the following (abstracted) code:

```java
if (input > 1000) {
    // Show your error message here
}
```

Optionally, you should also hide the error if the input is valid. This is such that the user won't be confused when they enter a valid input but the error message is still shown. This can be done with an `else` statement:

```java
if (input > 1000) {
    // Show your error message here
} else {
    // Hide your error message here or do whatever you want
}
```

Hope this helps!

P.S. Here's what the code would look like when adapted to your current code:

```java
// ...
if (custID > 1000) {
    custIDInput.setError("Please enter a number between 0 and 1000");
} else {
    // Hide the error message
    custIDInput.setError(null);

    i.putExtra("Value1", name);
    i.putExtra("Value2", custID);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

---

For more information on what "relational operators" (or the conditional operators) mean, check out this [guide from Trinket on "Conditionals and Logic"](https://books.trinket.io/thinkjava/chapter5.html).

Answer (score 0):

Change code in onClick like below.

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Customer.class);

    name = nameInput.getText().toString();
    address = addressInput.getText().toString();
    custID = Integer.valueOf(custIDInput.getText().toString());

    if(custID > 0 && custId <= 1000) {
        i.putExtra("Value1", name);
        i.putExtra("Value2", custID);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    } else {
       custIDInput.setError("Error Customer ID: enter number 1-1000");
    }
```

Comment: If you've read the question _closely_, you would've noted that the conditions of the customer ID are _between_ 0 and 1000. This means that `0` is inclusive in the condition.

Comment: By the way, please consider explaining how your code is different from OP's code and how it solves the problem.

Comment: @MonicaBreitweiser Hey, don't try to hustle on doing things like developments, there are lot of limits by learning and doing something just watching YouTube videos  that you mentioned. It's pretty normal that you got stuck, being stressed. Just get some fresh air, and find the right way to learning android. There are lot of books that you can learn the android, A to Z. Cheer up!

Comment: Thanks. I had to erase my comment from before. But I appreciate the support.

Answer (score 0):

First Create this class:

```
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;

public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

    private int min, max;

    public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
        this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
        this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {   
        try {
            int input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());
            if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                return null;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }     
        return "";
    }

    private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
        return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
    }
}
```

Add This line of code to you EditText (XML)

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Set your filter to your editText in Kotlin/Java file

```
et.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax("0", "1000")});
```

Comment: Please consider explaining how your code is different from OP's code and how it solves the problem, instead of merely copying and pasting code from elsewhere.